# Процентное значение в DB2

Tags: база-данных, db2, ibm

Как хранить процентное значение в СУБД IBM DB2? 
Тип float или же decimal?

Comment: Float -приблизительное. Decimal - точное. Тебе что больше подходит?

Comment: ну я точно не знаю, я еще не шарю в таких вещах). дай совет если знаешь кое что ))

Comment: А тогда какая тебе разница? Возьми Decimal. Тем более что он "первее" по алфавиту.

Comment: так получиться:
`create table bms."t1"(
"name" decimal(2,2)
);

insert into bms."t1"
values(10.05);`

что то у меня данные не вводятся, ошибка

Comment: Ну, наверное, наступил срок, когда надо всё же почитать документацию и узнать, что означает каждое из чисел в определении размера для типа `DECIMAL`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужна высокая точность, то DECFLOAT.
Если устраивает хранение с округлением, то FLOAT.
Если нужно точное соответствие формату, то DECIMAL(m, n)